# Launch app in chroot environment

Tags: applications, root-access, security, storage, privacy

I want to setup a chroot environment on my android x86 installation in which I can perhaps run or install various apks.
Is there any way to launch an application in a custom chroot environment?

Comment: You may want to [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/242367/edit) your post to include which emulator environment (including OS version) you are using and the type of behavior you are expecting out of the chroot environment.

Comment: Keep backups or snapshots of your Android-x86 to revert to, should something goes wrong and you cannot fix it. You are unlikely to get a Linux like chroot implementation in Android. You can however try using a secondary user to prevent app interactions with sensitive data. Work profile can also be used in this regard.

Comment: I specifically want to use chroot, it's for a personal project.

Comment: I don't think chroot will not work in Android for apps. Android bases on Linux but the Android app system works totally different. Only for command-line programs (on adb or inside termux) chroot can work.

Comment: I see, well thanks.